# I want to Fetch the Sales by Customer and Grouped in Different Payment Methods

Tags: sql, postgresql

My database schema name is Warehousemangement and I'm Doing this work in PostgreSql, My Database Design is

[image: Relational Design of Warehouse Management System]

My Query is

**Fetch Sales Order and Grouped in Different Payment Methods**

```
SELECT s.* FROM warehousemanagement.tbl_sales AS s INNER JOIN warehousemanagement.tbl_payment as p
ON s.sales_id = p.transaction_id INNER JOIN warehousemanagement.tbl_paymentmethod 
AS pm ON p.paymentmethod_id = pm.paymentmethod_id GROUP BY pm.payment_method;
```

It Shows Error:

```
ERROR:  column "s.sales_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select s.* from warehousemanagement.tbl_sales as s inner joi...
               ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your query - there is no GROUP BY in your query, but in the error message. Please show us the real query that produces the error

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Comment: The error you show is due to misspelling `payment` as `payement` but it doesn't match your query as @a_horse_with_no_name already stated.

Comment: I edited my Question@a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Format your code properly.  No one is going to read that one-liner code.

Comment: I properly my Code @Eric

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `SELCT *` and `GROUP BY` will never work.  That's not a proper code.

Comment: So What is the Code for the desired Result....@Eric

Comment: You have to show us desired output. *My query is to fetch sales order and grouped in different payment methods* ... you cannot have grouped and unit levels in same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select s.contact_no, pm.payment_method, sum(pm.amount)
from warehousemanagement.tbl_sales s inner join 
     warehousemanagement.tbl_payment p
     on s.sales_id = p.transaction_id inner join 
     warehousemanagement.tbl_paymentmethod pm
     on p.paymentmethod_id = pm.paymentmethod_id
group by s.contact_no, pm.payment_method;
```

This sums the amounts by different payment methods for each customer.

Comment: Its Shows Correct Output for the query you said but My query is to fetch sales order and grouped in different payment methods